# bash to remove path in second select

Tags: bash

In the `bash` below  a user selects a file to be used in the first `select` and then that digits in that file are used to automatically 'select`the second file.  The problem is that when the second file is selected the path appears in the name so the`bash` errors.  I can not seem to fix this and need some help.  I apologize for the long post, just trying to make sure all files needed are here.  Thank you :).

**Bash**

```
FILESDIR=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools
ANNOVARDIR=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/vcf/overall/annovar

PS3="please select a file to analyze with a panel: " # specify file
select file in $(cd ${FILESDIR};ls);do break;done
    file1=`basename ${FILESDIR}/${file}`
    printf "File 1 is: ${file1} and will be used to filter reads, identify target bases and genes less than 20 and 30 reads, create a low coverage bed for vizulization, calculate 20x and 30x coverage, and filter the vcf for the 98 gene epilepsy panel"
for file in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools/$file; do
 bname=$(basename $file)
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
 grep -wFf /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/panels/EPILEPSY_unix_trim.bed $file > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/panel/reads/${pref}_EPILEPSY.txt
 done
# filter vcf
printf "\n\n"
file2=`basename $(ls ${ANNOVARDIR}/${file%%_*}*)`
        printf "File 2 is: ${file2} and will be used filtered using the epilepsy genes"
 pref=${bname%%}
 awk 'NR==FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} FNR==1 || ($7 in a)' /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/panels/EPILEPSY_unix_trim.bed $file2 | awk '{split($2,a,"-"); print a[1] "\t" $0}' | cut -f2-> /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/vcf/panel/annovar/${pref}_Epilepsyfiltered.bed
```

**files for first select** `if the user selects 12311_base_counts.txt)

```
12311_base_counts.txt
45611_base_counts.txt
```

**files for second select**

```
12311_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno_removed_final (this one is automatically selected because it has the same starting digits as the original file)
45611_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno_removed_final
```

**bash with error** (`this portion of the path is the problem I think, /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools/`)

```
1) 12311_base_counts.txt   
2) 45611_base_counts.txt   

please select a file to analyze with a panel: 7
File 1 is: T31129_base_counts.txt and will be used to filter reads, identify target bases and genes less than 20 and 30 reads, create a low coverage bed for visualization, calculate 20x and 30x coverage, and filter the vcf for the 98 gene epilepsy panel

ls: cannot access /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/vcf/overall/annovar//home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools/T31129*: No such file or directory/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools/
File 2 is:  and will be used filtered using the epilepsy genes
```

Comment: I just had the `basename` in the wrong place. Silly mistake I apologize and thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
file2=$(ls ${ANNOVARDIR}/`basename ${file%%_*}`*)
```

Comment: Ewww. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- and run this whole thing through http://shellcheck.net/.